# align span in the middle of a fixed size div

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed size div with a background image, and I want text to be aligned directly in the middle. Vertically and horizontally.

I'm able to get the horizontal alignment, but can't for the life of me get it to be vertically aligned. I've seen answers on here, but couldn't find anything that worked for a fixed size div.

You can see the blue border around the span. If I could just move that down to be always centered for any text(as long as it doesn't get too big) I'd be there.

```css
div {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/I86rTVl.jpg);
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    
}

span {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    font-size: 72px
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div>
  <span>Testing for fiddle</span>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: http://howtocenterincss.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of many possible solutions, here is a modern `flexbox` technique.

Check the browser compatibility table for [**Flexbox**](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

```css
div {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center; /* Center vertically */
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/I86rTVl.jpg");
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}
span {
  /* position: absolute; Remove */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Avoid text wrapping */
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  font-size: 72px
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <span>Testing for fiddle</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I do actually want text-wrapping btw. But it appears to work fine with removing that line.

Comment: Yes, you can remove that line if you want text to be wrapped. I was just trying to align vertically matching your current output.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it's the one I ultimately used. But the other answers are great too!

Comment: Do you know which browsers support this? I've noticed it not work on safari on both PC and mobile. Not sure of the versions. Haven't tried IE, but works on chrome and FF

Answer (score 2):

Try the good old table/table-cell technique. Works down to IE9 :)

```css
div {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/I86rTVl.jpg);
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display:table;
    
}

span {
    display:table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    font-size: 72px
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div>
  <span>Testing for fiddle</span>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Absolute positioning**

With the parent set to `position:relative` set the child's position to top:50% and the translate it back up by half it's own height.

```css
div {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/I86rTVl.jpg);
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border: 1px solid blue;
  font-size: 72px
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <span>Testing for fiddle</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If you use this method, the aligned element gets blurry sometimes unless you use preserve-3d on parent:
parent (div in your case) {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/kvqLnchw/1/

```
  div {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/I86rTVl.jpg) no-repeat;
    width:500px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align:center;
}

span {

    border: 1px solid blue;
    font-size: 72px

}
```